# Is an App removed from the App Store if it is in "Processing App Transfer"

Tags: ios, app-store

I am going to transfer an App that is currently on the App Store from my personal account to an Organisational account and have been reading the docs here:

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f

It doesn't say anything about being removed from the app store, but it does say that the process can take up to 2 days and that during this time the App status is changed to Processing App Transfer. As this status takes over from Ready For Sale, does that mean that the app is no longer Ready for Sale and as such removed from the App Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who has this question, I contacted Apple and got the following response:

> The app’s visibility on the App Store will not change for the duration
>   of the transfer.

In practice this was correct. My app was still available throughout the entire process.